# RadioButton's state isn't persisting between callbacks?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DataGrid that looks like this:

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgICDCodes" runat="server" bodyHeight="300px" CssClass="tblScroll" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="clsGridHeaderText"
            HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Select
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelect" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Code") %>'
            AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" Width="10%"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

The `Text` property of the RB is used in the code-behind to set a variable that keeps track of the unique `Code` for that row, when the user selects it.

What is happening is the user enters their search parameters, the application builds the columns and populates this grid with results from the DB.

When the user selects a row this is what happens:

- Page_Load fires
- `IsPostBack` is `true`
- Some logic requires the grid to be re-bound

  - This drops all of the columns, except for the radio button, and re-adds them to the grid
- Another method is called which re-sets the DataGrid's DataSource to a persistent DataTable
- The row is de-selected on the UI.

*Somewhere* the checked state of this radio button is either being lost or "rewritten", but I absolutely cannot figure out where and I'm wondering if it has something to do with the postback nature? But if I remove `AutoPostBack="true"` then the radio button doesn't behave as one would expect and they can select multiple rows in the grid.

New to web dev so I don't really know what to do...

**EDIT** Adding some Page_Load related code:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Call mfpEnableDisableControls()

        cmdSearch.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return mfpValidate();")
        txtNoOfRecords.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "return mfpIsNoOfRecords(this);")

        Call mfpFillPresumptiveRuleCombo()
        mfpFillTierCombo()

        cmdRefresh.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return mfpIsNoOfRecords(document.forms[0].txtNoOfRecords, true);")

        mInitializeSpread(dgCodes, False, True, True)
        mInitializeSpread(dgCodes_AdditionalTier, False, True)
        mInitializeSpread(dgCodes_AdditionalCompliance, False, True)

        Call mfpLoadData("-1", vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNullString)
        `mfpLoadData executes some stored procedures, puts the results into the DataTables used in mfpBindGrid, and then it calls mfpBindGrid
    Else
            If Request("__EVENTTARGET").StartsWith(dgCodes.Controls(0).Controls(0).UniqueID.Replace("$", ":") & ":") = False Then
                Call mfpBindGrid(False)
            End If

        End If
End Sub
```

`mfpBindGrid`:

```
Private Sub mfpBindGrid(ByVal aBlnReloadFromDB As Boolean, Optional ByVal aCurrentPageIndex As Integer = 0)

    mfpFindRadioButton(dgCodes.Controls) 'This just checks which RB was selected and stores a Code in a variable on the form

    mfpInitGridColumns() 'This drops everything after the first column (the RB) and re-adds them

    mFillGridData(mobjDTCodes, dgCodes, Not aBlnReloadFromDB, ViewState, aCurrentPageIndex)
    mFillGridData(mobjDTTierCodes, dgCodes_AdditionalTier, Not aBlnReloadFromDB, ViewState, aCurrentPageIndex)
    mFillGridData(mobjDTPeerCodes, dgCodes_AdditionalCompliance, Not aBlnReloadFromDB, ViewState, aCurrentPageIndex)

    'These methods configure the grids (dgName) based on the DataTable (mobjDTname) and re-set their DataSource to the tables passed.

End Sub
```

It's a bit of a clusterfsck. Basically the order of operations:

Page Loads -> Is Not Post Back -> mfpLoadData() -> BindGrid()

User Clicks Search -> PageLoad -> Is Post Back -> BindGrid() -> Search Click Event Fires -> mfpLoadData() -> BindGrid()

User Selects Row -> PageLoad -> Is Post Back -> BindGrid()

Maybe it's my lack of experience with web dev, but this seems like a colossal mess and something somewhere probably doesn't need to be done.

Comment: try using something like `OnCheckedChanged=some function in the code behind` you have a post back set for the radio button but its not set to do anything.

Comment: On a previous question of yours, you mentioned that the DataGrid binds on every PostBack. This would cause the values to be reset. Can we see the code to your `Page_Load` event?

Comment: @MaCron I had previously tried handling the `CheckedChanged` event but due to the postback and the databinding screwing with the grid the event itself was never firing.

Comment: @j.f. Added more code

Comment: Yeah, your issue is that you are rebinding the grid on each and every PostBack. This will reset your RadioButtons. Sounds like you may have to rework some of that logic. I can't see the rest of the app, but my guess is that you are binding in a lot of places where it probably isn't necessary. You could start with removing the bind when `IsPostBack == true`.

Comment: You're most likely correct. Previously this form only had 1 grid and everything worked, but needing to add child grids that populate on the main one has been quite the can of worms.

Comment: Do you have other postbacks that need to rebind the grid? If not you could use a checkchanged event, and rebind the grid in the event as opposed to in the post back.  although I am still uncertain why you are needing to rebind the grid on each postback, it seems like overkill.